# on symbian i only got "view details" but not that "open" option for 80% of my apps in app-manager, why and how to fix?

Tags: symbian

on symbian i only got "view details" but not that "open" option for 80% of my apps in app-manager, why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

App manager is not ment for opening you apps - I don't have the Open otion in 100% of my apps